# JSON SWIFT OpenWeatherMapAPI

Tags: json, swift, weather-api, openweathermap

I am building an app that is trying to pul data from OpenWeatherMap API, but at this line:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil) as NSDictionary
```

I am getting this error: 'AnyObject? is not convertible to NSDictionary'; did you mean to use as! ?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func ConfirmLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBOutlet weak var LocationSearchLabel: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var LocationLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var LocationTemperature: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getOpenWeatherFeed("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func getOpenWeatherFeed(urlString: String)
{
    let urlAddress = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlAddress!) {(data, response, error) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.pushDataToLabel(data)})
    }

    task.resume()
}

func pushDataToLabel(weatherData: NSData){
    var jsonError: NSError?

    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil) as NSDictionary

    if let name = json["name"] as? String{

        LocationLabel.text = name}

    if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double{
            LocationTemperature.text = String(format: "%.1f", temp)
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cast from AnyObject? to Dictionary is unsafe as AnyObject could be an object which is not of the type Dictionary so the cast operator has to be `as!` or `as?` wether you want to implicitly unwrap the cast result. Also AnyObject? is an optional. 
The solution would be to unwrap the result of the JSON deserialization first, then cast to Dictionary:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil) {
    if let dictionary = json as? Dictionary {
        //work with dictionary here
    } else {
        //The provided data is in JSON format but the root json object is not a Dictionary
    }
} else {
    //The provided data is not in JSON format
}
```

In the first line, the JSON data is deserialized, which could produce any object or it could fail. if it fails, nil is returned and the outer else case is called. if the serialization is successful, the json object gets casted to a Dictionary, which you can then use. A short but unsafe solution would be

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil)! as! NSDictionary
```